# Convert XElement to string

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a simple XElement object

```
XElement xml = new XElement("XML",
    new XElement ("TOKEN",Session["Token"]),
    new XElement("ALL_INCLUSIVE", "0"),
    new XElement("BEACH", "0"),
    new XElement("DEST_DEP", ddlDest.SelectedValue.ToString()),
    new XElement("FLEX", "0")
);
```

Where want to dump out the contents into a string. Exactly like how `Console.Writeline(xml);` does, but I want the contents in a string. I tried various methonds. `xml.ToString();` doesn't return anything on its own.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`ToString` should most definitely work.  I use it all the time.  What does it return for you in this case?  An empty string?  My guess is that something went wrong building your `XElement`.  To debug, rewrite the code to add each of the child `XElement`s separately, so that you can step through your code and check on each of them.  Then before you execute the `.ToString`, in the Locals window, look at the `[xml]` variable expanded to xml.

In short, your problem is happening before you ever get to the `ToString()` method.

Answer (score 19):

`ToString` **works**, but it returns content including XElement tag itself. If you need for **Inner XML** without root tag ("" in your example), you may use the following extension method:

```
public static class XElementExtension
{
    public static string InnerXML(this XElement el) {
        var reader = el.CreateReader();
        reader.MoveToContent();
        return reader.ReadInnerXml();
    }
}
```

Then simple call it: `xml.InnerXML();`